# How to change default ViewController of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I create basic `TabBarController` with 2 `ViewControllers`.
It worked but it have bug and i want something about it.

***Problem1.***

When I run (default `ViewController is FirstViewController`) name of `SecondViewController` in `TabBar` is not appear.

[image]

I want following this picture.

[image]

***Problem2.***
In my code default view is `FirstViewController`.
If I want to set default view is `SecondViewController` 
by Same Tab Bar(`FirstView` Tab : Left ,and `SecondView` Tab : Right)
following this picture. How to resolve it.

[image]

**This is my example code**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *firstNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
    firstNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *secondNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];
    secondNVC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tabController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNVC, secondNVC, nil];
    tabController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thank You. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[viewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[viewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController3" bundle:nil] autorelease];


    navControl1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    navControl2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    navControl3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

    navControl1.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    navControl2.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    navControl3.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navControl2,navControl1,navControl3, nil ];

    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"1"];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2.png"]];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"2"];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab11.png"]];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"3"];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab5.png"]];

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];

    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];
```

Comment: thank you very much.
I use [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"1"];

^^

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem2.** If I want to
>   set default view is SecondViewController by Same Tab Bar(FirstView Tab
>   : Left ,and SecondView Tab : Right). How to
>   resolve it.

**Solution:**

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: **Problem 2** : I use this code [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; and [tabController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; but it's not work. T^T

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**

try to set a title for the view controllers.

**Problem 2:**

You just set selected index of the tabBarController to 1, that should do it.

Comment: **Problem 1** : yes, i already to set a title for both ViewController but it's not occurs.

**Problem 2** : I use this code [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; and [tabController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; but it's not work. T^T

Comment: mmmm just a question, why are you setting it up by code ?? why aren't you using storyboard ?!? that would solve all you issues :\

Comment: in my project using Code only...sorry T^T

Answer (score 0):

**Problem1**

You haven't set `tabbarItem` for each navigation controller, I think you should set up a `UITabBarItem` with title first, then assign it to `tabbarItem` property to navigation controller.

**Problem2**

Just as @Kumar says.

Comment: Like: UITabBarItem *item = [UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
secondNVC.tabBarItem = item; And for Problem2, you'd better call 'setSelectedIndex' method after '[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];'