# How to change the background color of the TabBar to translucence in iOS6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

My `UITabBarController`  is extend from `UITabBarController`, the background color is translucence in `iOS7`,but black in iOS6. How to change the background color to translucence in `iOS6`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can set transpertant image

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];
```

check link

[tab bar contrller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966536/how-to-change-default-viewcontroller-of-uitabbarcontroller/20967680#20967680)

Comment: nice Help Without Transpernt I can't able to set uicolor

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the tint property with your custom color like

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way but in `iOS7` by default

`[tabBar setTranslucent:YES];` so you got translucence backGround of tabBar But in the `iOS6` you do manually

```
[tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Just try it and also  try with **@Retro's** answer and another option is

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.6]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set as following.

```
 [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundColor:
 [UIColor  whiteColor]];
 [self.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO]; 
 [self.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```